# Deriving PMF from Berger & Berry (1988)

Tags: probability, negative-binomial-distribution

The [paper](http://ifmlab.for.unb.ca/people/kershaw/Courses/Research_Methods/Readings/BergerJO1988a.pdf) didn't specify the PMF for the image on pg 161.

Based on image and description:

1. Stop when observe 4 successes and 4 failures
2. X axis is not limiting trials
3. p(heads) = p(tails)

Former discussion on a previous [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskStatistics/comments/b9jbql/distribution_help/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf).

I think thinking about how to classify it. Is it a negative binomial conditional on a binomial this?

Negative binomial formulation of: probability of r failures given k successes (tails given heads). Problem is trials are fixed.

Condition on Binomial - probability of at least 4 heads in n trials.

I also know I can simulate the results to verify.